# How does my class know about another class when it shouldn't?

Tags: php, macos, sqlite

Recently, I have been given an SQLite3 database that I will be using to query with PHP. My question is, where should the SQLite3 database be stored so that my PHP application can find it? I've never worked with SQLite3 before, but I am assuming that there is someplace in the filesystem that is reserved specifically for databases. I am using Mac OS X, by the way.

Comment: And that's awkward. I was typing up a question yesterday but figured it out before I posted. It remembered my question today, and while I replaced the body I forgot about the title. I suppose I can't change it either, haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store anywhere (in the scope of your project) you want, just store the relative or absolute path to your sqlite file in a setting file so it can be changed easily in the future.

Edit: Take a look at this http://www.sqlite.org/different.html

"
Single Database File

An SQLite database is a single ordinary disk file that can be located anywhere in the directory hierarchy. If SQLite can read the disk file then it can read anything in the database.
"

So just make sure that the file is readable by your code.

Comment: You can store it anywhere accessible to PHP/Web Server! :D

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I skimmed through the man pages of sqlite3 and didn't see anything on this. I'll mark this answer when it lets me.

Comment: No problem, one more thing, please match the title with the content of your question. It is a little bit confusing.

Comment: @DanielMartin At http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.open.php it says exactly what is needed to open a SQLite3 database.